# Filling Grayscal Image C#

Tags: c#, image-processing, grayscale, lpr

I'm designing an LPR application for academic purpose, and one of the steps in the detection step is to fill the holes in a dilated edge detected grayscale image, I would like to know if there's a C# code that could do that

Comment: You might want to look at [AForge.NET Framework](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/) which is entirely written in C# and is available on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=aforge.net). The framework contains classes for edge detection, hole filling and much more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use opencv library, which works well under C# also that you may be know already about. you find functions to
 - detect outer contours
 - detect inner contours, and make some morphological processes that help you in filling holes.